# How to change button hinge of macbook pro 2017?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

[image]last week left cmd button on my macbook pro 2017 w/o touchbar broken
i swapped that with right command button but some of inner hinge pins are broken too

can i change that too? i barely use right cmd button and Apple does not have Store in my country
it currently looks like this

you can see that right-up and button-left pins are broken

Comment: The keyboard needs to be replaced, unfortunately

Comment: Not just keyboard replacement, but whole top.